# Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: example.com. is not in the cert's altnames

Tags: node.js, http, dns, dropbox, host

I'm trying to POST a file to `content.dropboxapi.com` and am getting the error `Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: example.com. is not in the cert's altnames` where `example.com is the hostname of my own server. I'm on Node 13.12 and [Got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) version 10.2.

When I manually change the request header for `host` to `content.dropboxapi.com`, the request works. Are there security implications to this change?

edit: My request code looks something like this:

```js
import { pipeline } from "stream";
import fs from 'fs
import got from "got";

const readStream = fs.createReadstream("hello-world.txt")

const dropboxGot = got.extend({
  prefixUrl: "https://content.dropboxapi.com"
  responseType: "text",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer dfjaiods ... adsfnioa",
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
  }
)

const writeStream = dropboxGot.stream.post("2/files/upload", {
  "Dropbox-API-Arg": "DROPBOX_ARGS...",
 })

pipeline(readStream, writeStream)
```

Comment: It is not clear where your `example.com` comes from. The HTTP `host` header should be the hostname you are trying to reach, as taking from the URL. So it would seem in your case it needs to be `content.dropboxapi.com` and nothing else.